# Is $ \{ \infty \} $ open or closed in $ \overline{ \mathbb R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is $ \{ \infty \} $ open or closed in $ \overline{ \mathbb R}$ ?
Here  $\overline{ \mathbb R} = \mathbb R  \cup \{ \infty \} \cup \{ -\infty \} $.

Comment: I would prefer the notation $+ \infty$, however it is a closed point. $\overline{\mathbb R}$ is homeomorphic to a closed compact interval.

Comment: Although the answers given are more insightful, notice also that you should know the answer before you can prove it: $\{\infty\}$ is finite, hence compact, hence closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's closed in the usual topology.

Your question seems to assume it's either open or closed, but most sets are neither open nor closed.

We want to define such things as $\lim\limits_{x\to3} f(x) = +\infty$.  That has to mean that for every open set $A$ containing $+\infty$, there is some open set $B$ containing $3$ small enough so that if $x\in B$ and $x\ne 3$, then $f(x)\in A$.  It is from such considerations as that that the definitions of open and closed subsets of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ are derived.

A set is closed precisely if its complement is open.  The set $(-a,a)$ is open.  The union of every set of open sets is open.  The union of all sets of the form $(-a,a)$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$, and clearly excludes both $+\infty$ and $-\infty$.  The set $\{-\infty\}\cup(-\infty,b)$ is open.  So we have
$$
\big(\{-\infty\}\cup(-\infty,b)\big)\cup\big( \bigcup_{a>0} (-a,a) \big)
$$
is open.  Its complement is $\{+\infty\}$.  So that set is closed.

Comment: +1: "Your question seems to assume it's either open or closed, but most sets are neither open nor closed." There's an old saying. A set is not like a door. It can be open, closed, both or neither.

Comment: @JimConant I liked your "A set is not like a door..."

Answer (score 2):

Another way to look at it is to consider the complement $\{-\infty\} \cup \mathbb{R}$ which is a neighborhood of all of its elements, i.e. it is open.  Hence its complement, $\{\infty\}$, is closed.